# Heroku: My Django app is giving Application Error H14: "No Web Processes Running"

Tags: django, heroku

According to the Heroku site when I get error H14 "No Web Processes Running" it's because I need to [scale up dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes) by:

`heroku ps:scale web=1`

However, when I do that I get the following error:

```
Scaling web processes... failed
 !    No such type as web
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I want to get my site back up!

When I run `heroku ps` I see nothing.

UPDATE: It's not detecting my Procfile. I don't have a Procfile explicitly and didn't use one before... is it absolutely necessary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this recently as well, my web was working fine without any `Procfile`, until recently...
My fix was simply to add a `Procfile` as follows:

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload
```

Then push to heroku.

Comment: Thanks I tried adding a Procfile but no luck... do I just name it `Profile` or `Procfile.txt`... do I put it into the main app directory, or where `manage.py` is located?

Comment: In the git repository root is where I have it, exactly as `Procfile`. Push, then I'd try `heroku ps:scale web=1` again if needed. This might help: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django

Answer (score 1):

For Heroku you need to add a Procfile.

1. add a Procfile on same level like your manage.py file. It should be in your root directory. Be sure that you create a Procfile not a Procfile.txt or else just Procfile
2. in your Procfile add:

   > web: gunicorn projectname.wsgi
3. add in your requirements.txt gunicorn

   > gunicorn==20.0.4

If you activate automatic deploy you can try it again.
If you can remove the app, remove it and deploy it again.